# How to comment a line and insert a another line below it?

Tags: regex, sed, solaris, sunos

I would like to comment a line 2 in `abc.c` and add the text `New second line` in line 3 of the file.

`abc.c`:

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

My modified file should look like

```
First line
//Second line
New second line
Third line
```

I have tried using the command

```
sed 's/Second line/\/\/Second line\
New second line/g' abc.c > tmp.c && mv tmp.c abc.c
```

But it gives the error as "sed command garbled" on sunOS 5.10

Can anyone please tell me what's the correct command to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed "s/Second line/\/\/&\\
New second line/g" abc.c > tmp.c && mv tmp.c abc.c
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i.bak -e"s/Second line/\/\/&\nNew second line/;" abc.c`

Afterwards content of file:

```
First line  
//Second line  
New second line  
Third line
```

Comment: Doing a 'p' duplicates every line in the file as well, which then has to be suppressed with the '-n'. What's the point? '\n' doesn't work on all platforms (e.g. macOS), whereas the embedded literal newline does. The {} are unnecessary.

Comment: I did not manage to use your answer on my machine, (GNU sed version 4.2.1 on Windows). Probably because I do not know how to use the embedded newline. I would appreciate learning that, based on your explanation. My version is a one-liner which works on my machine. So I thought I provide what works for me, as an alternative answer. I admit the use of `-n` AND `p` is inefficiently redundant. I will edit the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think OP might have the same trouble understanding embedded-newlines as I have. So you are probably set for many upvotes (at least an acceptance by OP and an upvote by me) if you explain it.